# SSL for server aliases

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a website and  multiple domains are pointed to it.

For example: `sub.abc.com`, `sub.bcd.com`, etc.

The site is hosted on a single IP on a dedicated server. 
I'm using `ServerAlias` for pointing multiple domains to the single site.

How should I purchase certificates for this setup? Can I buy one individual certificate for each domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to purchase a single SSL certificate with a [Subject Alternative Name (SAN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName) for each domain that you use unless you wish to break browsers that do not support SNI.

Comment: Can i buy one single domain certificate for each domain?

Comment: You buy one certificate with all of the domains on it.

Comment: Ok, i meant, can i buy regular domain certificate for each domain instead of this?

Comment: No. Not unless you want to: 1. Have 1 IP per domain. Or 2. Leave out browsers that don't support [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)

Comment: Thank you. I think i got you. So typically i normal SSL certificate will require that, each domain (though aliases) must be pointed to different IP. So IP's are different for every SSL domain configured?

Comment: Yes, unless you want only browsers that support SNI to connect correctly.

Comment: One last question, after configuring SAN certificate,can i add more domains to the list later on?

Comment: No. You cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Should you need to add in additional TLDN during the lifespan of a SAN certificate, all you need to do is to request a re-issue which is free of charge.  During the reissue process, you have the option to add in additional SAN.  Depending on the brand you might either need to pay for additional SAN or in GeoTrust's case, the SAN cert covers up to five total names,  Common name + 4 SAN.  Anything after the first 5 and up to the 25th will require additional purchase.